# CefSharp Browser Refresh Loop

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

Im using cefsharp latest version on winforms with .net 4.5 (53.0.1). After some dom changes on html, browser loads the first init url every second and it never finishes. I found this method : "SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgsmightly" to solve my problem but there is nothing on the screen if i use this method

```
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            settings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs();
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-path", appPath + @"PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll");
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Comment: WinForms does not use OffScrren rendering, so avoid using that method. Check the Debug.log file. You should also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve